# Angular Perfs : everything in Detached DOM tree

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on an SAP, and try to improve perfs. I try to find some memory leaks, and found some tuto about chrome dev tool Profile -> Take Heap Snapshot.

I'm trying to find some Detached DOM tree, but it seems that a lot (all?) of my elements (divs, ul...) are detached DOM tree, while all those elements are really still in my DOM.

Do i miss something? why all that elements appears in the detached DOM tree lists?

For example :

Here's a directive :

```
<ul class="calque" id="listeCalques">
  <li ng-repeat="calqueModel in dirCtrl.viewController.getListeCalques() | orderBy:'$index'" ng-model="calqueModel">
      <div class="btn btn-primary btn-calque" ng-click="dirCtrl.viewController.basculerVisibilite(calqueModel)">
          <img src="/Content/Images/pictos/oeil.png" ng-class="{'opacite50': !calqueModel.visible}" />
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

here i have the oeil.png as detached (several times):

[image]

But we can see here that those images are still in the DOM :

[image]

Comment: An obvious guess would be those are deleted elements either referenced in some variables or not yet cleaned up by GC. If no proper answer is given try the in-depth [articles on devtools site](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/).

Comment: they may be not same object, angular create a copy every time when template is re-compiled..

Comment: I've added some code in my example. I've clicked on the Timeline -> Collect garbage before the snap, and this is what happen when i just load the SAP, i didn't do anything yet, so nothing is supposed to be deleted 
I also added a console.info() in the directive compile function, and i can see that it's only executed once, so it cannot be copy